# Repeating patterns in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am new with Django. I want to know what the best way would be to repeat a piece of html in a template multiple times using block inheritance (for multiple `script` or `style` tags) in a way I can use a view to pass an array to the template.

I was thinking this could be done by using something like multiple inheritance but I don't know how to begin implementing such a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think you can do something like this.

```
def ExampleView(request):
    items=___ #Whatever objects you want to work on
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'items': items,})
```

And then your template.

```
template.html
...
{% for item in items %}
    <-- Whatever you want to do for each item -->
{% endfor %}
```

If I misunderstood, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm your question is not clear for me yet but in general this is how you make templates in Django.

You have one main file called `base.html`, it's the base template that all your other templates will extends/inherit it. In `base.html` you can define `block`, and in the child templates, you can add information to that block:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/main.css">
    {% block additional_css %}{% endblock %}        

    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    {% block additional_js %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

So you can see in the example, I defined 3 blocks: `additional_css`, `content` and `additional_js`. In your child template you can extends those blocks and include whatever info you want, for example you have a template name `child.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block additional_css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/child.css">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Welcome to my site!</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

If you want pass a list to your template in block, that's straight forward. Let say your a list call `all_js_files` that passed from your view, your template can have:

```
{% block additional_js %}
    {% for js_file in all_js_files %}
        <script src="{{ js_file }}"></script>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Just to give you the basic idea.